# How to get substring from wstring in c++?

Tags: c++

How to get substring from a wstring?

I tried to work with substr function as specified in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/

It is printing some bad characters.

How can I achieve that without use of boost library?

```
vector<wstring>test;
test.push_back(L"OK1");
test.push_back(L"OK2");
test.push_back(L"OK3");

wstring arrayOfSplitted[200];
int noOfSplitedStrings = 0;

//const wchar_t*arrayOfSplitted[200];
for (auto const& w : test)
{
    const wchar_t* st = w.c_str();
    //wprintf(L"Splitted: %ls\n", st);
    arrayOfSplitted[noOfSplitedStrings] = st;
    wprintf(L"Splitted: %ls\n", st);
    noOfSplitedStrings++;
}
int length = arrayOfSplitted[1].length();
cout << length << endl;

wstring temp = arrayOfSplitted[1].substr(0,2);
wprintf(L"Splitted: %ls\n", temp);
```

Comment: What you mean by "bad characters" ?

Comment: @Veena Post the code you're having problems with.

Comment: Can you show some code? Thanks.

Comment: Is the thing you are displaying the results in able to display wide characters?

Comment: @utnapistim,@LogicStuff I have edited my question

Comment: @Jerome some characters like ?,8, some symbols irrelevant to the context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wprintf(L"Splitted: %ls\n", temp);
```

that's wrong you pass the var `temp` not the string itself.
Use :

```
 wprintf(L"Splitted: %ls\n", temp.c_str());
```